# how to determine amplitude and frequency of Oscillator with random fluctuations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, random, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

I have the following system $$\ddot{x}+w^2 x=0,$$  with the following initial conditions: $\dot{x}(0)=0$ and $x(0)=x_o$, the solution reads: $$x(t)=x_o cos(t).$$ Now I want to include the fluctuations due to thermal fluctuations (in frictionless system), so the equation of motion is modified as $$\ddot{x}+w^2 x=\lambda \zeta(t),$$ with $\dot{x}(0)=0$ and $x(0)=0$ solution reads:
$$x(t)=\lambda \int_0^{t}cos(t-t')\zeta(t')dt'$$
1- I would like to know how to include the initial condition $\dot{x}(0)=0$ and $x(0)=x_o$ in the solution?

2- how to obtain the frequency spectrum due to these fluctuations?

Comment: The last formula gives a particular solution. The general solution is obtained by adding the complementary solution. (Of the inhomogeneous and homogeneous equations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the correlation function for the noise. I guess it is Gaussian being thermal noise and set
$$
\langle\zeta(t)\zeta(t')\rangle=\sigma^2\delta(t-t')
$$
where $\sigma$ is a constant. The general solution of the forced harmonic oscillator can be written down, with the given initial conditions,
$$
x(t)=x_0\cos(\omega_0 t)+\frac{\lambda}{\omega_0}\int_0^t\sin(\omega_0(t-t'))\zeta(t')dt',
$$
where I have slightly changed the OP notation by setting $w\rightarrow\omega_0$. This will yield for the correlation function
$$
\langle x(t)x(t')\rangle=x_0^2\cos^2(\omega_0t)+\frac{\lambda^2}{\omega_0^2}
\int_0^t dt'\int_0^t dt''\sin(\omega_0(t-t'))\sin(\omega_0(t-t''))
\langle\zeta(t')\zeta(t'')\rangle,
$$
that is
$$
\langle x(t)x(t')\rangle=x_0^2\cos^2(\omega_0t)+\frac{\lambda^2}{\omega_0^2}\sigma^2
\int_0^t dt'\sin^2(\omega_0(t-t')).
$$
I think you can go on from here.

Comment: In driven harmonic oscillator, after sufficeint time, the oscillation is dominated by the particular solution according to the driven force. what about case with noise (due to diffusion or thermal flactuations), whould the solution be dominated by the particular solution too?